# Filter where value is in column of another DataFrame

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to create a new column in a DataFrame which will be 'true' if the value of another column is in a column of another DataFrame. I have tried the following, but the syntax for `isin()` is wrong I believe because I am passing a DataFrame with a single column.

customers:

```
customer_id     name
          1     John
          2     Mary
          3     Jane
          4     Jack
          5     Emma
```

customer_referred_customer:

```
from    to
   1     3
   2     4
```

Result:

```
customer_id     name    is_referral
          1     John          false
          2     Mary          false
          3     Jane           true
          4     Jack           true
          5     Emma          false
```

Attempt:

```
customers.withColumn(
    "is_referral",
    F.when(
        F.col("customer_id").isin(
            customer_referred_customer.select("to")
        ),
        F.lit("true"),
    ).otherwise(F.lit("false")),
)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: can you add some sample input data & excepted data ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create list of the check column and use .isin()

```
df.withColumn('is_referral', df.customer_id.isin(df1.select("to").rdd.flatMap(list).collect())).show()


+-----------+----+-----------+
|customer_id|name|is_referral|
+-----------+----+-----------+
|          1|John|      false|
|          2|Mary|      false|
|          3|Jane|       true|
|          4|Jack|       true|
|          5|Emma|      false|
+-----------+----+-----------+
```

Answer (score 2):

I would do it like this:

```
customers.join(
customer_referred_customer,
customers.customer_id ==customer_referred_customer.to,
 "left")
.withColumn("is_referral",
 f.when(customer_referred_customer["to"].isNull(),f.lit("false"))
.otherwise(f.lit("true"))
.select(customers["customer_id"],customers["name"], "is_referral")
```

Answer (score 1):

Use semi join and anti join. You didn't provide the data so I can't test, but the idea of the code is:

```
customers = customers.join(
    customer_referred_customer, 
    customers.customer_id == customer_referred_customer.to, 
    'left_semi'
).withColumn(
    'is_referral', 
    F.lit('true')
).unionAll(
    customers.join(
        customer_referred_customer, 
        customers.customer_id == customer_referred_customer.to, 
       'left_anti'
    ).withColumn(
        'is_referral', 
        F.lit('false')
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `full outer` join & then derive new column `is_referral` using `withColumn("is_referral",col("to").isNotNull())`

Check below code.

```
customers
.join(customer_referred_customer,customers.customer_id == customer_referred_customer.to,"full")
.withColumn("is_referral",col("to").isNotNull())
.select("customer_id","name","is_referral")
.orderBy(col("customer_id").asc())
.show(false)
```

```
+-----------+----+-----------+
|customer_id|name|is_referral|
+-----------+----+-----------+
|1          |John|false      |
|2          |Mary|false      |
|3          |Jane|true       |
|4          |Jack|true       |
|5          |Emma|false      |
+-----------+----+-----------+
```